# Hooks dependency API call if changes found React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hooks dependency API call if changes found React:

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({})
         const [id, setId] = useState(1)
         const [idFromButtonClick, setIdFromButtonClick] = useState(1)

         const tick = () => {
             axios
               .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
               .then(res => {
              console.log(res)
              setPost(res.data)
               })
               .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err)
               })
         }

         useEffect(() => {
                const interval = setInterval(tick, 1000)
                return () => {
                  clearInterval(interval)
                }

         }, [idFromButtonClick])

         const handleClick = () => {
            setIdFromButtonClick(id)
         }
```

I'm calling api to after a second but i want api only call it there is difference how can i make it please guide

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on there is a difference? Which changes or difference on you would like to call the API? Thank you!

Comment: What this demo is doing it's calling api after a second but i want not to call after a second it should check if there is anything new interm of id or title than it will call otherwise not

Comment: The code you have right now makes a call to the API every one second until you cancel the timer, when the `idFromButtonClick` changes in the state. You mention checking for changes in the `id` or title values, why don't you change that in the `useEffect` hook to this?: `useEffect(()=>{}, [id])`. I think Alex's approach of adding the API call in the hook is the best approach, just add a `setTimeout` in it in order to wait for 1 second. Honestly I'm a bit confused in terms of what you want to do and what is the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You would like to call API with a 1-second delay

```
 useEffect(() => {
     setTimeout(
         ()=>{axios
             .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
              .then(res => {
                     console.log(res)
                     setPost(res.data)
                   })
              .catch(err => {
                     console.log(err)
             })}
          ,1000)


          }, [idFromButtonClick])
```

You don't need use `setInterval` just call API within setTimeout.
check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-api-hz0mf) out

Comment: just one time? or when button clicked?

Comment: forget you have button click just see title changes found it should update

Comment: Weather it came from click event or directly

Comment: for clarification, waiting 1 second after button clicked then fire call api.right?

Comment: let me explain in other way lets say i have a api that get call after one second interval and returns an object i.e {id: 1, title: post} after one second it return same i want if there is difference value in id or title (let's say i updated id 2 it should updated) then network should call.